# Trying to join multiple tables without all the pair of common columns hence the values are repeating from the last tables. Need help to solve this

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I Have the following lines and result is added in image link. The results of 1adjust` to be joined, there is no platform or date column in it, hence the records are repreated. Is there a way to avoid this. This will cause issue in visualizations at campaign level when the repeated items are getting summed

```
with 
sent as (
    select campaign_name, date(date) as date, platform, count(id) as sent
    from send
    group by 1,2,3
),

bounce as (
    select campaign_name, platform, count(id) as bounce 
    from bounce
    group by 1,2
),
open as (
    select campaign_name, platform, count(id) as clicks
    from open
    group by 1,2
),
adjust as (
    select campaign, sum(purchase_events) as transactions, count(distinct adjust_id) as sessions, sum(sessions) as s2, sum(clicks) as ad_clicks
    from adjust
    group by 1
)
select 

s.campaign_name,
s.date,
s.platform,
s.sent,
(s.sent-b.bounce) as delivered,
b.bounce,
o.clicks,
a.ad_clicks,
a.sessions,
a.s2,
a.transactions

from sent s
join bounce b on s.campaign_name = b.campaign_name and s.platform = b.platform
join open o on s.campaign_name = o.campaign_name and s.platform = o.platform
left join adjust a on s.campaign_name = a.campaign
```

[See the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ggzq.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please refer to the image link. I dont have a common column for one table and because of that the values will be repeated twice based on the other columns of different table. I need to record only the first values of transactions for each campaign